# Why would I ever use Array.toSource?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Apparently there's a non-standard method of [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [`toSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSource). As per the example..

> ```
> var alpha = new Array('a', 'b', 'c');
>
> alpha.toSource();   // ['a', 'b', 'c']
> ```

.. it seems to do the same thing as [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var alpha = new Array('a', 'b', 'c');

JSON.stringify(alpha);
```

So why would I want to use `Array.toSource`?

Comment: not sure. running the test code you have (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSource)) gave me an error in Chrome, as it shows in the compatibility table

Comment: In IE toSource doesn't work too.

Comment: You wouldn't. Don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. `toSource()` is [a holdover from the Netscape days](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.3) and has been obsolete for ages. It was, however, the only built-in way to convert an object to its source representation before what we now know as JSON, let alone the respective de/serialization APIs, ever came into existence.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty interesting!

Answer (score 1):

**toSource()** function only coverts an array to string format whereas **JSON.stringify()** is capable of converting an array as well as a javascript object to string format

Comment: So I could just do `Array.prototype.toSource=function(){return JSON.stringify(this)}` and have my own fake of toSource?

Comment: .. and while I'm at it I could go general and make `toSource=JSON.stringify` :P

Comment: Yes, of course my friend :) you can make your fake version of it